# Inserir data no Mysql

Tags: php

Saudações.

Estou fazendo upload de uma planilha e salvando no banco, porém não estou conseguindo salvar a data e hora. Normalmente utilizo o código abaixo para fazer isso:

```
   $ultima_venda = explode(" ", $ultima_venda);
   list($date, $hora) = $ultima_venda;
   $data_sem_barra = array_reverse(explode("/", $date));
   $data_sem_barra = implode("-", $data_sem_barra);
   $data_sem_barra = $data_sem_barra . " " . $hora;
```

Tentei dessa forma tbem:

```
implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $ultima_venda)));
```

Estou recebendo a data vindo de um array, acredito que seja isso que estou tendo dificuldades.
Segue meu código para upload da planilha excel:

```
 <?php

//import.php
include '../conexao.php';
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

//$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

if($_FILES["import_excel"]["name"] != '')
{
 $allowed_extension = array('xls', 'csv', 'xlsx');
 $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["import_excel"]["name"]);
 $file_extension = end($file_array);

 if(in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension))
 {
  $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['import_excel']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
  $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
  $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

  $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);

  unlink($file_name);

  $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

  foreach($data as $row)
  {
   $insert_data = array(
    ':ide'  => $row[0],
    ':terminal'  => $row[1],
    ':modelo'  => $row[2],
    ':ultima_venda'  => $row[3],
    ':sonda'  => $row[4],
    ':periferico'  => $row[5]
   );

   $ultima_venda = explode(" ", $ultima_venda);
   list($date, $hora) = $ultima_venda;
   $data_sem_barra = array_reverse(explode("/", $date));
   $data_sem_barra = implode("-", $data_sem_barra);
   $data_sem_barra = $data_sem_barra . " " . $hora;

   var_dump($row[3]);

   $query = "INSERT INTO metroatm (ide, terminal, modelo, ultima_venda, sonda, periferico, criado) VALUES (:ide, :terminal, :modelo, :ultima_venda, :sonda, :periferico, NOW())";
   $sql = $conexao->prepare($query);
   $sql->bindParam(':ide', $ide);
   $sql->bindParam(':terminal', $terminal);
   $sql->bindParam(':modelo', $modelo);
   $sql->bindParam(':ultima_venda', $data_sem_barra);
   $sql->bindParam(':sonda', $sonda);
   $sql->bindParam(':periferico', $periferico);

   $sql = $conexao->prepare($query);
   $sql->execute($insert_data);
  }
  $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Solicitação enviada com sucesso</div>';
  
 }
 else
 {
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Apenas .xls .csv or .xlsx arquivo permitido</div>';
 }
}
else
{
 $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Por favor, seleciona o arquivo</div>';
}

echo $message;

?>
```

Eu preciso salvar a data vindo da planilha na coluna ultima_venda `':ultima_venda'  => $row[3]`
Esse é o formato que estou recebendo da planilha:
18/02/2022 06:56:20

Answer (score -2):

Olá, pelo que entendi, você está querendo formatar uma data BR para inserir no Database no formato 'Y-m-d H:i:s' (se eu entendi corretamente kkkkk).

A primeira coisa que eu sugiro (principalmente se a versão do php for 7+) é olhar as documentações das classes nativas do php.
Seria fundamental você ler [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) e também [Formatos Datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.date.php)

Bom, vamos a solução (espero que lhe atenda)

```
<?php

//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dateInput = '18/02/2022 06:56:20';

$dateOutput = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    $dateInput,
    new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo')
);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($dateOutput, true) . '</pre>';
```

O output do código acima:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2022-02-18 06:56:20.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

Para extrair somente a data no formato que desejar (vide link formatos datetime, você pode fazer desta forma acrescentanto `format()`:

```
$dateOutput = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    $dateInput,
    new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo')
)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($dateOutput, true) . '</pre>';
```

O output do código acima:

```
2022-02-18 06:56:20
```

Se trabalhar com timestamp no database você pode utilizar o mesmo código, com uma única diferença, no lugar de `format()` utilizar `getTimestamp()`, dessa forma:

```
$dateOutput = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    $dateInput,
    new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo')
)->getTimestamp();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($dateOutput, true) . '</pre>';
```

O output do código acima:

```
1645178180
```

Espero ter ajudado!

**Lembrando que o createFromFormat lhe dá uma boa abertura para criar datas de diversos formatos possíveis, assim como o format() lhe dá a possibilidade de configurar as saídas**

*Qualquer dúvida consulte as documentações de date, datetime, etc*

Comment: Cara, acredito que seja algo simples, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Coloque seu bloco de código dentro de um try catch, e verifique na conexão do DB se você setou `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  para você poder depurar o código.

Veja se a conexão do banco está retornando, por exemplo, um select comum, e execute um `DESC metroatm;` e veja se o tipo do campo data está correto.

Sua dúvida não ficou muito clara, se puder passar o erro que está dando, ou mostrar um debug do código pra ver a estrutura dos dados, ajudaria.

Comment: Consegui amigo, eu não fui especifico mesmo. No lugar onde faço o array, consegui formatar a data do horário brasileiro para o formato aceito no mysql, fiz da seguinte forma:

  foreach($data as $row)
  {
   $insert_data = array(
      ':ide'  => $row[0] ,
      ':terminal'  => $row[1] ,
      ':modelo'  => $row[2] ,
      ':ultima_venda'  => $row[3] = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row[3]), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      ':sonda'  => $row[4] ,
      ':periferico'  => $row[5]
   );

Comment: Cara, não sei se percebeu, mas você fez exatamente o que te passei acima... a única coisa que muda, é que você utilizou outras funções pra fazer a mesma coisa que te passei.

Mas enfim, se funcionou, se você se resolveu, é o que importa.